# Strings over written by "mov" instructions

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm working with MASM.

I have a 64 bit variable and I need to store a 32 bit input from a register into the lower half of the 64 bit variable.

First, I move the address of the lower half into the register:

```
mov ebx, OFFSET num1+32
```

Then, I use the `PTR` instruction to store the 32 bit input into the second half of the variable:

```
mov DWORD PTR [ebx], eax
```

However, everytime the second line runs, one of my strings declared in the ".data" get over-written in memory. It goes from:

> 45 6e 74 65 72 20 46 69 72 73 74 20 48 61 6c 66 20 6f 66 20

to

> 45 6e 74 65 72 20 46 69 bb bb bb bb 48 61 6c 66 20 6f 66 20

The thing changed is `bb bb bb bb` as shown above.

The `bb bb bb bb` is what I input to be stored in the 64 bit variable before the two lines above are ran.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but this may be where you're going wrong:

```
mov ebx, OFFSET num1+32
```

What you're doing here is getting the address of `num1` + 32 **bytes**, which happens to be in the middle of one of your strings. I'm guessing that you thought what this did was get the address of `num1` + 32 bits.

This will move the address of the lower-portion of `num1` into `ebx`:

```
mov ebx, OFFSET num1+4
```

As you can see, I'm offsetting num1 by 4 bytes, which is equivalent to 32 bits, which is what I believe you wanted.

**If that was explained poorly, which is probably was, here's a simplified message:**

Given: `mov (register), (base) + (offset)`

What you put in offset will be an *x* amount of *bytes, not bits*.

Comment: Thank you very much, good sir! That was exactly what I was looking for. I totally forgot about DWORD moving in bytes instead of bits for the (offset).